# Conexão Banco de Dados Reativo

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Estou desenvolvendo uma app com Spring Boot e tenho uma classe de configuração que gera um @Bean DataSource.

Gostaria de gerar níveis de conexão alternativos de conexão ao banco de dados, como se as variáveis de ambiente estiverem incorretas, utilizar dados de application.properties, caso este também esteja, utilizar classe de configuração, independente desta ordem, gostaria de um resultado parecido, é possível configurar desta forma, tem alguma doc que posso seguir ?

Acredito ter um ambiente mais dinâmico e reativo para conexão desta forma.

Classe Bean de DataSource

```
package foo.bar.configuration;

import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DatabaseDriver;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class DataBaseConfiguration {

    private final static String DATABASE_CONNECTION_ROOT_USERNAME = "foo";
    private final static String DATABASE_CONNECTION_ROOT_PASSWORD = "bar";
    private final static String DATABASE_CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foobar";

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(DatabaseDriver.MYSQL.getDriverClassName());
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(DATABASE_CONNECTION_URL);
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername(DATABASE_CONNECTION_ROOT_USERNAME);
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword(DATABASE_CONNECTION_ROOT_PASSWORD);
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi bem o seu problema: você terá informação de configuração em diversos lugares, vários _property source_, por exemplo? Dê uma olhada em _import configuration_, _property sources_, etc. Além disso, parece não ter nada a ver com reatividade, uma vez que JDBC não é reativo, sendo por padrão _blocking_ -, se o seu problema é este, busque por _clients_ SQL que o são.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. Sim acredito que tenha errado ao afirmar sobre reatividade, confesso que ainda estou aprendendo um pouco, achei que a expressão, seria mais adequada ao questionamento, porem teria, alguma dica para clients sql reativos ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para este problema aprimorei a classe acima, para utilizar de duas fontes, arquivo application.yml e também de dados em código, podendo expandir para outras alternativas de busca.

Da forma que construi ele irá buscar qual o profile definido, caso exista algum em especifico, ele irá utilizar os dados pre-definidos e construir a conexão, acredito ainda não ser a melhor forma, porem auxilia bastante com o meu problema.

```
@Configuration
public class DataBaseConfiguration {

    private final static String DATABASE_CONTAINER_CONNECTION_ROOT_USERNAME = "foo";
    private final static String DATABASE_CONTAINER_CONNECTION_ROOT_PASSWORD = "foobar123";
    private final static String DATABASE_CONTAINER_CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bar?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        this.setConnectionConfiguration();

        final DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(DatabaseDriver.MYSQL.getDriverClassName());
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(this.url);
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername(this.username);
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword(this.password);

        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }

    private void setConnectionConfiguration() {
        if(Arrays.stream(environment.getActiveProfiles()).anyMatch(profile -> (profile.equalsIgnoreCase("container")))) {
            setterConnectionValues(DATABASE_CONTAINER_CONNECTION_ROOT_USERNAME, DATABASE_CONTAINER_CONNECTION_ROOT_PASSWORD, DATABASE_CONTAINER_CONNECTION_URL);
        }
    }

    private void setterConnectionValues(String username, String password, String url) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```